# Plug-in development - adding attribute to existing item in AndroidManifest

Tags: phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

A great new plugin was just added to pg.build called LaunchMyApp which allows an app to be launched from an url. 
The problem with this is that when I open my app from the browser, it creates an instance of the app "inside" the browser. If I then send the app to the background and open it normally from the launcher, this creates two instances of my app. 
I guess some would want this behaviour, but to the users of my app I think it will be confusing - so I decided to write a plug-in for running the app as a single instance.

The plug-in itself is extremely simple since it is only supposed to add the attribute

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

to the application tag in the androidmanifest.

I can see how I can add new nodes, but not how to add attributes to existing ones. 
Is this supported in plugin.xml?